# Windows 7 - computer restarts every 1 hour and say "Boot device not found"

Tags: windows-7, bsod

Since yesterday, my computer hangs and restarts automatically approx every 1 hour approximately. Also **occasionally**, the system does not boot and fails with the error "boot device not found".

I don't remember installing anything new. I tried looking at the Task Manager just before it freezes and found nothing suspicious. EventLog has no information. It just says "Windows unexpectedly rebooted" after reboot, but there is nothing when it freezes. I cleaned up the startup tools using "msconfig".

Is this some kind of a virus (boot sector virus) as sometimes it is not able to boot. My hard drive is an SSD and I did chkdsk and found nothing.

Is there anything that I could do without formatting and reinstalling?

Comment: Select **Disable automatic restart on system failure** in the F8 boot menu, then edit your question to add the error codes that appear when you get the blue screen.

Comment: Did you try checking the SMART status of your HDD? [Speedfan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) is a good place to start. (If they come back green, then do what DragonLord says)

Comment: Thank you DragonLord and EntropyWins. The firmware for the ssd was outdated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the STOP code on the blue screen as suggested by DragonLord. If the error indicates a hard disk problem, check the firmware version of your SSD and install the latest version. I had similar problems with an OCZ SSD, which were resolved by updating the firmware.

Comment: The firmware version was the problem. When I updated to the new version, it fixed it. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can try pressing F8 during boot and  rebooting from the last known good boot in the menu selection.

You might also try using your Win 7 CD, booting into recovery mode and restoring from one of the save points.

Comment: F8 is what I do to boot when it fails. It works for that time but fails occasionally when it reboots next time.

I am afraid that I disabled save points sometime back and that's not a solution.

Comment: Well, then I think that you might be out of luck.  Even if you reinstall Windows, it will save the old Windows directory and other existing directories so you could do some type of recovery as well....like restoring needed registry keys or data in one of the other windows directory.