# Dell Precision 690 workstation - Boot device not found

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, boot, bios

My Dell Precision 690 workstation has stopped booting into Windows 7 altogether.

About a week ago, the BIOS started giving me a message that the amount of memory had changed from the default configuration. I thought this strange for a couple of reasons, the biggest of which being that I had done absolutely nothing to the configuration or even to the computer itself. No problems yet, it still booted fine.

Two days ago, however, it stopped booting to Windows altogether, telling me that there is "No boot device available." The BIOS lists the two SATA HDDs that are connected, but won't boot to either, giving the aforementioned error message.

Would this be a Windows error or a hardware error?

UPDATE: As I was writing this question, the computer allowed me to boot to Windows Startup Repair. As I have not created a restore point myself, I had to choose to use Startup Repair. After restarting, the number of SATA devices listed in the BIOS on startup increased from 2 to 9, and again showed me "no boot device available."

My problem is actually fairly similar to the problem [described here](https://superuser.com/questions/529597/windows-7-computer-restarts-every-1-hour-and-say-boot-device-not-found), with the exceptions that it is more common for the computer NOT to boot to Windows and that these are standard HDDs, not SSD.

Another UPDATE: [This is an example of what I get on startup](https://i.imgur.com/DXEmr2K). Shortly thereafter, the table is replaced with the "No boot device available" error.

[image: Screenshot of the SAS controllers boot screen]

Comment: Can you check first the devices listed in your BIOS and the amount of memory? You should be able to do that entering the BIOS (DEL, F1 or F2 keys) and verifying there.

Comment: In the boot sequence, it lists what appear to be the 9 identical entries - "#558 ID01 LUNx ATA", where the lower-case x is a number zero through 7, with zero appearing twice. These are exactly the devices that appear listed when it boots.

Comment: But can you please enter the BIOS to check it?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want me to check that I haven't already checked. I have the "onboard devices" displaying in the BIOS settings, but this lists nothing about the currently connected SATA devices. Sorry if I seem noobish or something, but I honestly am not sure what you're asking that I haven't already accomplished. // EDIT: the devices are all listed by the BIOS on startup.

Comment: [This is what I get on startup.](http://i.imgur.com/DXEmr2K.jpg)

Comment: Your workstation has a SAS (Serial attached SCSI) adapter. That one is compatible with SATA drives. So far so good. SCSI however also allows one device to have multiple logical units. (Think of a CD changer with a dozen CDs in it, or a card reader with multiple slots and you get the idea). However in your screenshot it is identifying the second HDD (unit 1) as a device with 8 LUNs. That is wrong and needs fixing.

Comment: Oh, my first thought when I read your posts title but before reading the actual text was "Empty BIOS battery".  This is the usual suspect when a motherboard forgets how much memory was previously installed, and the precision 690 is from 2009. Old enough for that to happen. If that on board battery also powers the information store for the SAS card then you have found your problem.

Comment: First, thank you for the edit. Second, thank you for the help, and I'll try to fix the problem with the second HDD. :)

Comment: What I think would help is that this message maybe is different from the one that the BIOS would report. Usually is the first screen inside the BIOS, after pressing del or F2, don't remember. There you would also see the amount of memory.

Comment: @Hennes Googling the problem has gotten me squat as far as how to fix it, only articles and definitions of LUNs. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: How is your HDD configured? As two single disks, or as a mirror? If it is as two simple disks you can try rescanning the bus. If it is a mirror you can pull the second disk and test it in another computer. (The PC should be able to boot from the first disk with all data).

Comment: They're two separate disks. I'll try rescanning the bus first.

Comment: Also, if it helps (which it very well might), the drive is a Seagate Barracuda 7200.10 750GB. I've heard a lot of negative things about them, which leads me to suspect that the drive has failed or I corrupted something in the Windows registry. Also, Windows only ever used 600GB or so, even though both HDDs together provide a TB and a half of space according to the labels on the drives. Just thinking out loud in case any of this information is useful (as I'm still scratching my head about this whole thing).

Comment: I've done some troubleshooting and I've been moving the HDDs around, and I've discovered that it is indeed one of the disks (most likely the one that all of the data is on) that is malfunctioning. The other disk is likely blank, as the computer doesn't boot to it at all and there doesn't appear to be an OS on it. I'm not big into hardware, so I'm not sure of this, but could the Windows registry and files all be on the malfunctioning drive, while the other just holds some data? Or since Windows only used roughly the equivalent of 3/4 of one disk, would that be the only one with data on it?